# How can I define unique epsilons with bounded range for floating point analysis?

Tags: error-propagation

I'd like to use Mathematica for analyzing error bounds in floating point code.  To do this, we can use the standard model for floating point error:

$$flt(a\oplus b) = (a\oplus b)(1+\epsilon_i)$$

Where $|\epsilon_i| < k$ where k is some small constant (depending on the operation).

So, I could write FltAdd, FltSub, FltMul, FltDiv, etc functions that compute the result with the extra error term.  *but* the trick is that the epsilon for each separate term has to be unique, so e.g. I can't use $\epsilon_0$ for A+B and C+D because in actuality they'll have different errors.  If I used the same error, an expression such as (A+B)/(C+D) would have the error cancel which isn't what happens.

So, I think I need to somehow build error terms with unique symbols, but I need them to be predictable enough that I can bound all the "sum" errors by e.g. $u$ and all the div terms by e.g. $u-2u^2$.

But, I'm not nearly good enough at Mathematica to do that so I thought I'd see what people suggest in terms of approaching this.

Comment: Do you know about interval arithmetic?

Comment: I'm aware of the concept at least, would you go that route and just compute on an interval type instead?

Comment: Yes, the rules are already built-in. See [`Interval Arithmetic`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/tutorial/Numbers.html#9265)

Comment: I'm not sure interval arithmetic is what I want.  It seems more suited to tracking the error associated with _one_ evaluation of the function, whereas I want to find a bound for the whole expression for all possible inputs.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
$Version

(* "13.1.0 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (June 16, 2022)" *)

Clear["Global`*"]
```

Use [`Around`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Around.html) (EXPERIMENTAL function introduced in v12.0)

```
Around[a, ϵ]
```

[image]

```
Format[ϵ[n_]] := Subscript[ϵ, n]

{#, #[Around[a, ϵ[1]], Around[b, ϵ[2]]]} & /@
  {Plus, Subtract, Times, Divide, Power} // 
 Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]

```
Assuming[ϵ > 0,
  {#, #[Around[a, ϵ]]} & /@
    {Sin, Tan, Sqrt, Exp, Log} //
   Simplify] //
 Grid[#, Frame -> All] &
```

[image]

**EDIT :** From the documentation, "For linear computations, Around[x, δ] behaves like a number whose values are distributed according to the normal distribution NormalDistribution[x, δ]."

```
TransformedDistribution[x + y,
 {x \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[a, ϵ[1]],
  y \[Distributed] NormalDistribution[b, ϵ[2]]}]
```

[image]

Comment: Excellent answer.  I think directly used this will overestimate the error, since e.g. for adding two values with (1+$\epsilon$) error on them, I'd expect the error to be bounded by $3\epsilon/(1-3\epsilon)$ but it gives me a good direction to start looking in.